# How to retrieve only the alphanumeric from a string in SQL/Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have a column that have to clean from numbers and spaces that looks like:

```
    XX = 
TERR
6 ST
3 ST
4 ST
 AVE
2 PL
2 PL
2 PL
2 PL
4 CT
2 PL
4 ST
3 ST
3 ST
```

I mean, I need the opposite function to Val(), but can't find it. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at [this code?](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=96594)

Comment: I did, but I was wondering if there's a simple function like Val. I also don't know how to use that code... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't a function for this, but as long as all of your text is either in the format **NUMBER TEXT** or **TEXT** (and not **NUMBER TEXT NUMBER**), you could use the following:

```
TRIM(Replace(Column, VAL(Column), '')) AS Result
```

Basically, use `VAL` to find the number in the text, and then replace it with a blank space, and trim the rest.

Comment: Sorry, whatever your column name is

Comment: It did it! thanks..! I edited your post slightly to reflect that both have to be the same column... thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I forgot to update all my sample data.  Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You want a simple function like the inverse of `Val()` to discard all non-alpha characters.  I don't know anything like that.  However, a solution based on regular expressions is easy.  The function below discards all characters which aren't letters.  Here is that function applied to some of your sample inputs.

```
? OnlyAlpha("TERR")
TERR
? OnlyAlpha("6 ST")
ST
? OnlyAlpha(" AVE")
AVE
```

You need to use this function from within an Access application session.  It will not be available when used in a query run from outside Access ... like from classic ASP, VBScript, Dot.Net, etc.

```
Public Function OnlyAlpha(ByVal strSource As String) As String
    Dim re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    re.Global = True
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.pattern = "[^a-z]"
    OnlyAlpha = re.Replace(strSource, vbNullString)
    Set re = Nothing
End Function
```

A comment got me thinking about performance, so I offer this version which I believe should perform significantly faster.

```
Public Function OnlyAlpha(ByVal strSource As String) As String
    ' early binding requires reference to Microsoft
    ' VBScript Regular Expressions:
    'Static re As RegExp
    ' with late binding, no reference needed:
    Static re As Object

    If re Is Nothing Then
        'Set re = New RegExp ' early binding
        Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") ' late binding
        re.Global = True
        re.IgnoreCase = True
        re.pattern = "[^a-z]"
    End If

    OnlyAlpha = re.Replace(strSource, vbNullString)
End Function
```

You can easily switch that code from late to early binding.  Early binding is useful during development because it allows Intellisense to help you.  And early binding can be significantly faster in some cases.  However, in this case the `RegExp` object is created once then re-used for later calls to the function.  Any speed advantage from early binding during object creation should be inconsequential.

Comment: Paste it into a standard code module.  Create a new module if needed, just don't name the module the same as the function name ... maybe name the module modOnlyAlpha.  There rest depends on the context where you want to use it.  If in a query ... `SELECT OnlyAlpha([your text field]) ...`

Comment: If a context other than a query, tell us about it.  :-)  Re-reading the rest of this thread I am unsure whether you actually want to preserve space characters.  If you do, simply add a space to the pattern: `re.pattern = "[^a-z ]"`

Comment: You can add a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions` to get early binding (in the VBA IDE window - `Tools -> References`). Also, if this regular expression is being reused many times, it may be better to cache the regular expression as a module-level variable.